# How to query scalable prices in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Dear stack overflow community,

This is my first post so please bear with me :)

I need to solve a SQL problem for a friend of mine.
He is running a web shop and wants to create a finance report.
The application he is using provides such functionality using an interface were MySQL queries can be executed.

I already created most of the report with my (limited) SQL knowledge, however I am struggeling to solve the last problem.
The goal of the report is to UNION and JOIN several tables to get an overview of all commissions, invoices and proposals with their respective articles and prices.

So what I did so far:

I did a union of commissions, invoices, proposals (lets call them receipt) and joined them with articles and prices.
That worked very well.

However, here is my problem:

An article could have multiple prices depending on the date of the respective receipt.
So I end up with more rows in my table as there should be.

There is a "valid_until" field within the prices table, which I have to use for the filter ... but how?

Example:

| receipt_id | receipt_date | article_id | article_price | valid_until | price_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 209986-1 | 2020-09-10 | 2925 | 13 | 2020-12-06 | 1 |
| 209986-1 | 2020-09-10 | 2931 | 13 | 2020-09-09 | 2 |
| 209986-1 | 2020-09-10 | 2937 | 12,6 | 2020-09-12 | 3 |
| 209986-1 | 2020-09-10 | 2980 | 12,32 | 0000-00-00 | 4 |

In this case, only price_id 3 is valid as the receipt_date is "2020-09-10".

My Query (with limited SQL knowledge):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM commissions UNION ALL SELECT * FROM invoices UNION ALL SELECT * FROM proposals) AS receipt
LEFT JOIN article ON receipt.article = article.id
LEFT JOIN prices ON article.id = prices.artikel
WHERE receipt.date <= IF(prices.valid_until = '0000-00-00', Date('3000-01-01'), prices.valid_until)
```

With that query I still get 3 results (price_id 4, 3 and 1).

I managed to identify the valid price using DATEDIFF(), ORDER BY and LIMIT, however MySQL does not allow to use LIMIT in sub-queries :(

Any help would be much appreciated.

KR,
Wlad

Comment: You'll get an answer faster if you paste into your question the minimal set of create statements and insert statements necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Wlad can you post the `CREATE TABLE` scripts to create your tables and also the `INSERT INTO` scripts to insert some data into your tables? or you could mock your tables up on a site like dbfiddle.com or sqlfiddle.com so we can have a more complete understanding of your table structure and data

Comment: Essentially as already mentioned, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far.
I already thought that it might be tough to help me with the information given.
However, it is hard for me to provide CREATE TABLE scripts, as I do not have direct access to the DB. Everything I do needs to be done through the application.
Also, the DB holds data I might not be allowed to share.

Still I try to come up with a representable dummy DB.

In the meantime, do you have an idea how to filter for price_id 3 in the above table without using GROUP BY and LIMIT?